# Blob name suffix restrictions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

[Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#resource-names):

> Avoid blob names that end with a dot (.), a forward slash (/), or a
>   sequence or combination of the two.

Isn't "or a sequence or combination of the two" redundant?

Names that end with a dot or forward slash is a superset that contains names that end with a sequence or combination of dot or slash.

Comment: It's explicitly clarifying that you can't have, say, a sequence of dots or slashes. Feel free to submit a pull request though if you feel it should be reworded.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The redundant is just an emphasizing about blob name not supposed to end with dot or slash. It can be understood in this way:

> Avoid blob names that end with a dot (.), a forward slash (/), let alone sequence or combination of the two.

So I think it doesn't need rewording as there's no ambiguity actually.